# R: How do I check week-to-week variation in a dataset?

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset

I have a dataset of daily exchange rate data for the Sudanese pound in 2018. I have a month, date, and year columns. It looks like this:

```
| Year | Month | Date | USDollar |
|------|-------|------|----------|
| 2018 |   6   |  10  |  38.50   |
| 2018 |   6   |  12  |  38.52   |
| 2018 |   6   |  14  |  38.61   |
| 2018 |   6   |  18  |  38.63   |
| 2018 |   6   |  21  |  38.63   |
| 2018 |   6   |  22  |  38.65   |
| 2018 |   6   |  23  |  39.41   |
| 2018 |   6   |  24  |  39.42   |
| 2018 |   7   |  02  |  39.43   |
| 2018 |   7   |  03  |  39.50   |
```

And so on. As you can see, I don't have data for every single day, but I do for most dates. What I want to see is to check month-to-month and week-to-week variation in order to see if there are any sudden spikes in the data. I want to find ways to 'cut' the data and to see if there are natural break points where the data suddenly goes up or down.

For now, I've simply created some monthly scatter plots using `scatter.smooth(df$month, df$usdollar)` and it does show that the exchange rate seems to balloon up around October, but I want to get more specific. How can I look at week-to-week variation and divide the data more narrowly? Ideally, I want to look at week-to-week variation and run summary statistics for each week. Is that possible?

I'm really new to R, so any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Using the `week` function from `data.table` you can add which week each day falls in

```
library(data.table)
df$Week<- week(with(df,paste(Year,Month,Date,sep='-')))

> df 
   Year Month Date USDollar Week
1  2018     6   10    38.50   24
2  2018     6   12    38.52   24
3  2018     6   14    38.61   24
4  2018     6   18    38.63   25
5  2018     6   21    38.63   25
6  2018     6   22    38.65   25
7  2018     6   23    39.41   25
8  2018     6   24    39.42   26
9  2018     7    2    39.43   27
10 2018     7    3    39.50   27
```

then you could take the mean by week/year with

```
aggregate(USDollar ~ Year + Week, df, mean)

  Year Week USDollar
1 2018   24 38.54333
2 2018   25 38.83000
3 2018   26 39.42000
4 2018   27 39.46500
```

---

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L), Month = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L), Date = c(10L, 12L, 14L, 18L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 2L, 3L), USDollar = c(38.5, 38.52, 38.61, 38.63, 38.63, 
38.65, 39.41, 39.42, 39.43, 39.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```